# P-value from proportional hazards regression object

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I'm running some proportional hazards regression models using the `survival` package in `r` and would like to know how I can access the overall p-value for the likelihood ratio test to include it in an `rmarkdown` document. I can run the regression models and print the outputs with appropriate p-values in the r console window, but I can't find the argument for p-values in the `coxph` class of objects.

Here's an example model:

```
library(KMsurv)
library(survival)

data(burn); attach(burn)
my.surv <- Surv(T1, D1)
coxph.fit <- coxph(my.surv ~ Z1 + as.factor(Z11), method = "breslow")
coxph.fit
detach(burn)
```

The overall p-value = 0.006.

Comment: unname(summary(coxph.fit)$logtest["pvalue"])

Comment: @COOLSerdash Please put as an answer and I'll tick (thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `summary(coxph.fit)$logtest["pvalue"]` to extract the p-value from the likelihood ratio test.